# How to disable numbering in latex?

Tags: latex, texmaker

I am new to latex and I wrote the below tex code on Texmaker editor.

What I want to do is to add the "University" section without any numbering preceeding it and to be centered horizontally, because when I run the code I find that the word "University" is displayed but it is preceeded by a number and I do not want to display any number preceeding that word.

**code**:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\author{Anan}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{University}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to edit your line 9:

```latex
\section{University}
```

this way:

```latex
\section*{\centering University}
```

since the command `\section*` produces unnumbered sections.

Further, if you want to to include an unnumbered section to your table of contents, you can add

```latex
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{University}
```

(this time *without* `\centering`) just after. The resulting code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\author{Anan}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{\centering University}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{University}
Text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\section*{\centering University}
    % * removes numbering for _this_ \section instance, 
    % \centering within environment centres the title.
```

Note however, that this is a local solution, and that it's better practice (and easier for you to make later document-global changes) to re-define the `\section`, `\subsection`, ... environments using the `titlesec` package, as is described well in Alan Munn:s answer in the following tex.stackexchange thread:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8546/section-heading-centering-problem